# Mounting an encrypted volume for a single user only

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

There is a CPU-intensitive app that generates very sensitive data. So far, this app has been running on a secluded Windows 10 computer and its data has been written to a BitLocker-encrypted volume.

Now, this app is going to run on a platform with massive CPU power. Many users log into this platform simultaneously, either locally or remotely via Remote Desktop and PowerShell. (Each with a separate user account.) It is important that those sensitive data remain encrypted to those other users. The question is, how to go about it? Clearly, a password-based BitLocker approach is no longer a valid solution, because once the volume is mounted, it is visible to all.

I considered EFS briefly, but EFS encrypts file contents only. The folder structure and the file names remain unencrypted. Is there a way to mount an encrypted volume in a way that only the mounting user can access it?

**Update:** I need to request the administrator of the platform to install my app. So, I can ask them to install any other apps too, including one that grants encrypted access.

Comment: Why isn't something like NTFS security sufficient? Or NTFS security + EFS (which would prevent users from reading filenames)?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator NTFS permissions are useless if the physical medium containing the data is stolen. That's why those data were encrypted even when they were on that secluded Windows 10 PC. I cannot discuss the robbery risk here, for security and NDA reasons. Just know that such a risk must be taken into account even if it does not exist.

Comment: @TheAmazingSpiderman: You can combine BitLocker _and_ NTFS security, can't you

Comment: @grawity It was what I did when the app was running on the secluded machine. But once the volume is mounted, it is no longer the encryption that protects my files. Plus, NTFS permissions impede mobility, unless all the computers to which the storage is connected are part of the same Windows Server domain.

Comment: @TheAmazingSpiderman: But once the OS has unlocked the data, it _doesn't make a difference_ whether it's disk-level or file-level encryption – it is in both cases managed by the OS, the keys are held by the OS, and the only wall between other users and the data is the same OS.

Comment: @grawity Yes. Exactly. That's what encouraged me to ask this question. Disk- and file-level encryption aren't that different. Yet, EFS restricts the access rights to one user account while BitLocker does it for the whole machine. Now, if only I could mount a volume or VHD so that only one user could see the resulting volume or have access rights... I am not saying your suggestion is not valid. It is just inconvenient and convenience sometimes leads to much productivity.

Comment: That still doesn't change much at all – in Windows, the "access rights" you mention on user-specific volume mounts would just be controlled by the same sort of permission checks.

Comment: @grawity NTFS permissions are not good replacements for encryption. They are easily circumvented. A local admin can do that. All it takes is curiosity. In Linux, one can easily mount encrypted volumes per-user. Theoretically, it is possible in Windows too. That's what I need. Sure, a local admin can attach a debugger, look for mounted volumes on other sessions (assuming he/she knows they exist) and try to snatch the encryption key off memory, but this one takes time, knowledge and abject malice (as opposed to curiosity).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into putting this data in a virtual machine (VM) with an encrypted virtual disk.  If the user is able to start the VM themselves, then the encrypted data is protected by permissions (only accessible to the permitted user), and the encryption key is provided on boot of the VM, which keeps the un-encrypted data in memory rather than on disk.

You should ensure that no un-trusted users on the system have Administrator privileges on the system, but that should go without saying.

Comment: Hmm... a VM needs an OS, and an OS means licensing and overhead concerns. But I'll investigate this course of action.